# Method in actionListener is not called

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, primefaces

Method editBook() in commandButton is not called and i cant understand why.The main issue is to make edition of dataTable in modal dialog. Any help would be great. This is my code.

index.xhtml :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
<h:form id="form">
        <p:dataTable id="table" var="book" value="#{booksManager.booksTable.booksList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                     rowKey="#{book.bookId}" selectionMode="single" dblClickSelect="true" selection="#{booksManager.selectedBook}"> 
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    update=":form:display"
                    oncomplete="dialog:bookDialog.show()"
                    listener="#{booksManager.prepareEdit()}"/>
            <p:column headerText="Autor"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" /> 
            </p:column> 
            <p:column headerText="Tytuł"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" /> 
            </p:column> 
            <p:column headerText="Data publikacji"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{book.publishingDate}" /> 
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <h:outputText value="#{booksManager.editedBooks}" />

        <p:dialog id="dialog"
                  header="Book Detail"
                  widgetVar="bookDialog"
                  resizable="false"
                  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">

            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

                <h:outputText value="Autor:" />
                <p:inputText id="AuthorEdit"
                             value="#{booksManager.selectedBook.author}" />

                <h:outputText value="Tytuł:" />
                <p:inputText id="TitleEdit"
                             value="#{booksManager.selectedBook.title}" />

                <h:outputText value="Data publikacji:" />
                <p:inputText id="DateEdit"
                             value="#{booksManager.selectedBook.publishingDate}" />

                <p:commandButton 
                                 process="display"
                                 actionListener="#{booksManager.editBook()}"
                                 value="Save"
                                 update=":form:table :form:dialog"
                                 oncomplete="dialog:bookDialog.hide()"/>   
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="E:" />
        <h:inputText value="#{booksManager.count}" />
        <h:commandButton value="P" action="#{booksManager.generateBooks()}" />
    </h:form>



</h:body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

editBook:

```
public void editBook(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("is in");
    selectedBook.setBookId(this.selectedBookBefEdit.getBookId());
    selectedBook.setTitle(this.selectedBookBefEdit.getTitle());
    selectedBook.setAuthor(this.selectedBookBefEdit.getAuthor());
    selectedBook.setPublishingDate(this.selectedBookBefEdit.getPublishingDate());
    editedBooks++;
    System.out.println(editedBooks);
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton 
      process="display"
      actionListener="#{booksManager.editBook(e)}"
      value="Save"
      update=":form:table :form:dialog"
      oncomplete="dialog:bookDialog.hide()"/>
```

Still does not work. Maybe is something wrong with passing event to method editBook()?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use the following package in your method :

```
   javax.faces.event.ActionEvent
```

If it is still not working
Look at here, [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183)

Answer (score 2):

Your `actionListener` EL expression does not match the method signature with the `ActionEvent` argument. If you intend to let JSF set and pass the default `ActionEvent` argument, then you should **not** be using any parenthesis in the expression.

Your initial attempt

```
actionListener="#{booksManager.editBook()}"
```

and your second attempt

```
actionListener="#{booksManager.editBook(e)}"
```

are therefore **wrong**. The right way is

```
actionListener="#{booksManager.editBook}"
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)